# Where is Unicode version of atof in Windows Mobile

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I have a C++ application where I'm replacing a number of sscanf functions with atoi, atof, etc... for performance reasons.  The code is TCHAR based so it's _stscanf getting replaced with _ttoi and [_ttof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hc25t012%28VS.80%29.aspx).  Except there isn't a _ttof on Windows Mobile 5, or even a _wtof for explicit wide character support.  I've ended up using _tcstod instead, but that takes an extra parameter that i'm not very interested in.  So any ideas why there is no _ttof, _tcstof() or _wtof in Windows Mobile 5.0.  [It's there in VS2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hc25t012%28VS.80%29.aspx).  Am I missing something really obvious here?

Comment: What is your problem of passing NULL in the extra parameter of the _tcstod function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems of Windows Mobile is the size of RAM and ROM on the device. Therefore a lot of the redundant routines are removed to make sure the OS is as small as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If the data you want to convert is guaranteed to be only in the ASCII charset you can always transform it to ASCII and cat atof, atol, atoi & friends.

I mean if you have something like this(pseudocode):

```
TCHAR buf_T[20]=_T("12345");
char buf_char[20];

from_TCHAR_to_ascii(buf_T,buf_char);

atoi(buf_char);
```